# Is it possible to play YouTube audio when android device is sleeping?

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

is it possible to play youtube videos in a service while the device screen is locked (display off)? The YouTube API provides several ways, how to play a video, however, when I lock the device the playback stops. Android MediaPlayer can be simply played from a service and screen lock doesn't affect it...

Anyone has some experiences in this?

Any advice is very appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: possible? yes but it could be some work.... use the api to get the feed for a video. many , many links included in feed include the RTSP link for audio. Ive played the audio this way ( outside of android using VLC or using some other rtsp client works ) . You just have to figure out where your android supports rtsp links like that. Have not done much there but others have.   http://snipplr.com/view/63341

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube SDK **prevents videos from being played in the background**, simply because any existing `YouTubePlayer` instance is destroyed when the Activity/Fragment that contains it is paused/stopped/destroyed.

Moreover, it detects when the video player is being covered (both partially or totally) by another view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was afraid of that... is there any way around this? :(

Comment: Not if you want to stick with the YouTube SDK, no.